# Implementing Jedis into Ktor build.gradle directly

Tags: jedis, ktor

I am tryng to use Jedis directly in my Ktor application. But I don't know how to implement it in build.gradle file. I tried this:

```
implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

But it doesn't work.

```
val jedis = Jedis("localhost") -> "unresoled reference Jedis" error.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

- Put `implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:3.4.0'` nested under `dependencies` in the build.gradle file
- Have your IDE load the gradle changes (Shift-Command-I for IntelliJ Mac)
- Use `import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis` at the top of your code file
- Then you can use the Jedis class just like in your question.

I tried using what you did, with 'SNAPSHOT' at the end, and it didn't work.